# Universal property of homotopy pullbacks

Tags: category-theory, derived-functors, model-categories, pullback

I am working in a model category $\mathcal C$. Given a fibration $p: Y \to B$ and a map $u : A\to B$ where $A$ and $B$ (and thus $Y$ also) are fibrant, it is know that the usual pullback $A\times_B Y$ is an homotopy pullback. I can prove that with an explicit description of the homotopy pullback, no problem.

Do we then have a "universal property" as follow?

> For any cofibrant $Z$ (let even assume $Z$ bifibrant if needed), and any maps $f:Z\to Y$, $g:Z \to A$ such that $pf \sim ug$, there exists a *unique up to homotopy* $k:Z \to A \times_B Y$ such that $g\sim \pi_1 k$ and $f\sim \pi_2k$.

(Where $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are the two projections from the pullback. And $\sim$ stands for "homotopic to"; either right or left, it does not matter here considering the assumptions of (co)fibrancy.)

I am able to prove the existence of such a $k$ (with moreover $g = \pi_1k$ instead of a mere homotopy). It is mostly a use of the homotopy lifting property. But I have trouble proving that two such solutions $k_1,k_2:Z\to A\times_B Y$ are homotopic. Again by the homotopy lifting property I can even suppose that $g = \pi_1k_1 = \pi_1 k_2$ because $\pi_1$ is a fibration (being the pullback of the fibration $p$). So under this hypothesis and the one that $\pi_2k_1 \sim f\sim \pi_2k_2$, I want to deduce that $k_1\sim k_2$.

Any idea? You can even suppose $u$ to be a fibration if it helps. I'm kind of circling around in my attemps and I came to wonder if it needs more assumptions on $\mathcal C$ to be true...

---

Addendum: there is surprisingly few documents on this "local definition" of an homotopy pullback, compared to the "global definition" as a right derived functor. Appart from the nLab which is kind of vague about the context in which this universal property holds, I did not find anything useful on the web. (Maybe I just lack the correct keywords though...)

Comment: This follows immediately from the universal property of derived mapping spaces into homotopy limits.  See, for instance, Proposition 18.1.10 in Hirschhorn's book.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov So you're saying that I need to assume that $\mathcal C$ can be promoted to a simplicial model category?

Comment: No, the same statement holds for any model category.  The simplicial enrichment is only necessary if you want to use the Bousfield-Kan formula for homotopy limits.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Without the simplicial enrichement, how is $\operatorname{Map}(X,Y)$ defined? Is it the mapping space coming from framings (I remember somethings along these lines in Hovey's book I think)?

Comment: Map(X,Y) is defined for any relative category (you don't need a model structure), see the papers by Dwyer and Kan.  References can be found here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial%20localization#definition